# Parse WebCacheV01.dat in C#

Tags: c#, parsing, esent

I'm looking to parse the WebCacheV01.dat file using C# to find the last file location for upload in an Internet browser.

> %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\WebCache\WebCacheV01.dat

I using the [Managed Esent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ManagedEsent/) nuget package.

- Esent.Isam
- Esent.Interop

---

When I try and run the below code it fails at:

```
Api.JetGetDatabaseFileInfo(filePath, out pageSize, JET_DbInfo.PageSize);
```

Or if I use

```
Api.JetSetSystemParameter(instance, JET_SESID.Nil, JET_param.CircularLog, 1, null);
```

at

```
Api.JetAttachDatabase(sesid, filePath, AttachDatabaseGrbit.ReadOnly);
```

I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.EsentFileAccessDeniedException' occurred
>   in Esent.Interop.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot access file, the file is locked or in use

---

```
string localAppDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
string filePathExtra = @"\Microsoft\Windows\WebCache\WebCacheV01.dat";
string filePath = string.Format("{0}{1}", localAppDataPath, filePathExtra);

JET_INSTANCE instance;
JET_SESID sesid;
JET_DBID dbid;
JET_TABLEID tableid;
String connect = "";

JET_SNP snp;
JET_SNT snt;
object data;
int numInstance = 0;
JET_INSTANCE_INFO [] instances;
int pageSize;

JET_COLUMNDEF columndef = new JET_COLUMNDEF();
JET_COLUMNID columnid;

Api.JetCreateInstance(out instance, "instance");
Api.JetGetDatabaseFileInfo(filePath, out pageSize, JET_DbInfo.PageSize);
Api.JetSetSystemParameter(JET_INSTANCE.Nil, JET_SESID.Nil, JET_param.DatabasePageSize, pageSize, null);
//Api.JetSetSystemParameter(instance, JET_SESID.Nil, JET_param.CircularLog, 1, null);

Api.JetInit(ref instance);
Api.JetBeginSession(instance, out sesid, null, null);

//Do stuff in db

Api.JetEndSession(sesid, EndSessionGrbit.None);
Api.JetTerm(instance);
```

Is it not possible to read this without making modifications?

---

**Viewer**

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/ese_database_view.html

**Python**

https://jon.glass/attempts-to-parse-webcachev01-dat/

- [libesedb](https://github.com/libyal/libesedb)
- [impacket](https://github.com/coresecurity/impacket)

Comment: The error is very explicit, the file is already in use, so it can't be opened.

Comment: I thought there might be an option I'd missed in the API to open as ReadOnly.

The file is always in use so I would expect it to locked for writing.

Comment: I think you're out of luck, the DB provider will always open it in exclusive access as it can read and write to the DB file.

Comment: If the program which has locked the DB has locked it in share mode you can always first create a copy of the file and then operate on it (if it's not very heavy).

Comment: I'll give the copy a try, thanks

Comment: The database engine will lock it exclusively, as Gusman said the first time. You will also get different results from Nirsoft. See https://managedesent.codeplex.com/discussions/580557 for some details.

Comment: Just a note... the technique that Nirsoft uses to get pass the locked database is to use the "shadow copy" feature to copy the database to another temporary location... and open the copy

Answer (score 1):

### Issue:

The file is probably in use.

### Solution:

in order to free the locked file, please stop the **Schedule Task** -**\Microsoft\Windows\Wininet\CacheTask**.

### The Code

```
    public override IEnumerable<string> GetBrowsingHistoryUrls(FileInfo fileInfo)
            {
                var fileName = fileInfo.FullName;
                var results = new List<string>();
                try
                {
                    int pageSize;
                    Api.JetGetDatabaseFileInfo(fileName, out pageSize, JET_DbInfo.PageSize);
                    SystemParameters.DatabasePageSize = pageSize;

                    using (var instance = new Instance("Browsing History"))
                    {
                        var param = new InstanceParameters(instance);
                        param.Recovery = false;
                        instance.Init();
                        using (var session = new Session(instance))
                        {
                            Api.JetAttachDatabase(session, fileName, AttachDatabaseGrbit.ReadOnly);
                            JET_DBID dbid;
                            Api.JetOpenDatabase(session, fileName, null, out dbid, OpenDatabaseGrbit.ReadOnly);

                            using (var tableContainers = new Table(session, dbid, "Containers", OpenTableGrbit.ReadOnly))
                            {
                                IDictionary<string, JET_COLUMNID> containerColumns = Api.GetColumnDictionary(session, tableContainers);

                                if (Api.TryMoveFirst(session, tableContainers))
                                {
                                    do
                                    {
                                        var retrieveColumnAsInt32 = Api.RetrieveColumnAsInt32(session, tableContainers, columnIds["ContainerId"]);
                                        if (retrieveColumnAsInt32 != null)
                                        {
                                            var containerId = (int)retrieveColumnAsInt32;
                                            using (var table = new Table(session, dbid, "Container_" + containerId, OpenTableGrbit.ReadOnly))
                                            {
                                                var tableColumns = Api.GetColumnDictionary(session, table);
                                                if (Api.TryMoveFirst(session, table))
                                                {
                                                    do
                                                    {

                                                        var url = Api.RetrieveColumnAsString(
                                                            session,
                                                            table,
                                                            tableColumns["Url"],
                                                            Encoding.Unicode);

                                                        var downloadedFileName = Api.RetrieveColumnAsString(
                                                        session,
                                                        table,
                                                        columnIds2["Filename"]);

                                                        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(downloadedFileName))  // check for download history only.
                                                             continue;

                                                        // Order by access Time to find the last uploaded file.                                                     
                                                        var accessedTime = Api.RetrieveColumnAsInt64(
                                                        session,
                                                        table,
                                                        columnIds2["AccessedTime"]);
                                                        var lastVisitTime = accessedTime.HasValue ? DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(accessedTime.Value) : DateTime.MinValue;


                                                        results.Add(url);

                                                    }
                                                    while (Api.TryMoveNext(session, table.JetTableid));
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    } while (Api.TryMoveNext(session, tableContainers));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // log goes here....
                }

                return results;
            }
```

### Utils

Task Scheduler Wrapper

You can use Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.TaskService Wrapper to stop it using c#, just add this Nuget package [nuget]:https://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/

### Usage

```
public static FileInfo CopyLockedFileRtl(DirectoryInfo directory, FileInfo fileInfo, string remoteEndPoint)
        {
            FileInfo copiedFileInfo = null;
            using (var ts = new TaskService(string.Format(@"\\{0}", remoteEndPoint)))
            {
                var task = ts.GetTask(@"\Microsoft\Windows\Wininet\CacheTask");
                task.Stop();
                task.Enabled = false;
                var byteArray = FileHelper.ReadOnlyAllBytes(fileInfo);
                var filePath = Path.Combine(directory.FullName, "unlockedfile.dat");
                File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, byteArray);
                copiedFileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
                task.Enabled = true;
                task.Run();
                task.Dispose();
            }

            return copiedFileInfo;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to get Adam's answer to work. What worked for me was making a copy with [AlphaVSS](https://github.com/alphaleonis/AlphaVSS) (a .NET class library that has a managed API for the Volume Shadow Copy Service). The file was in "Dirty Shutdown" state, so I additionally wrote this to handle the exception it threw when I opened it:

```
catch (EsentErrorException ex)
{   // Usually after the database is copied, it's in Dirty Shutdown state
    // This can be verified by running "esentutl.exe /Mh WebCacheV01.dat"
    logger.Info(ex.Message);
    switch (ex.Error)
    {
        case JET_err.SecondaryIndexCorrupted:
            logger.Info("Secondary Index Corrupted detected, exiting...");
            Api.JetTerm2(instance, TermGrbit.Complete);
            return false;
        case JET_err.DatabaseDirtyShutdown:
            logger.Info("Dirty shutdown detected, attempting to recover...");
            try
            {
                Api.JetTerm2(instance, TermGrbit.Complete);
                Process.Start("esentutl.exe", "/p /o " + newPath);
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                Api.JetInit(ref instance);
                Api.JetBeginSession(instance, out sessionId, null, null);
                Api.JetAttachDatabase(sessionId, newPath, AttachDatabaseGrbit.None);
            }
            catch (Exception e2)
            {
                logger.Info("Could not recover database " + newPath + ", will try opening it one last time. If that doesn't work, try using other esentutl commands", e2);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm thinking about using the 'Recent Items' folder as when you select a file to upload an entry is written here:

> C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent

```
string recent = (Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Recent));
```